# XTerm and a bold text

Tags: linux, fonts, xterm

This is my Xterm config:

```
XTerm*saveLines: 512
XTerm*reverseVideo: false
XTerm*reverseWrap: true
XTerm*fullCursor: true
XTerm*scrollTtyOutput: on
XTerm*scrollKey: on
XTerm*eightBitInput: false
XTerm*pointerColor: white
XTerm*pointerShape: left_ptr
XTerm*charClass: 37:48,45-47:48,58:48,64:48,126:48
XTerm*cursorColor: rgb:aa/aa/aa 
XTerm*cursorColor2: black

XTerm*color0:  rgb:71/71/71 
XTerm*color1:  rgb:cd/00/00
XTerm*color2:  rgb:b4/cd/00
XTerm*color3:  rgb:cd/cd/00
XTerm*color4:  rgb:71/71/71
XTerm*color5:  rgb:cd/00/cd
XTerm*color6:  rgb:00/cd/cd
XTerm*color7:  rgb:e5/e5/e5
XTerm*color8:  rgb:4c/4c/4c
XTerm*color9:  rgb:ff/00/00
XTerm*color10:  rgb:55/ac/55
XTerm*color11:  rgb:ff/ff/00
XTerm*color12:  rgb:46/82/b4
XTerm*color13:  rgb:ff/00/ff
XTerm*color14:  rgb:00/ff/ff
XTerm*color15:  rgb:ff/ff/ff


XTerm*colorBD: white
XTerm*colorUL: SkyBlue
XTerm*colorBDMode: on
XTerm*colorULMode: on
XTerm*underLine: on
XTerm*background: rgb:30/0a/24
XTerm*foreground: white 
XTerm*font: -*-monospace-medium-r-normal-9-140-*-*-m-*-* 
XTerm*font1: 5x7
XTerm*font2: 6x10
XTerm*font3: fixed
XTerm*font4: 9x15

XTerm*ScrollBar.Background: gray
XTerm*ScrollBar.thickness: 0
XTerm*ScrollBar.foreground: gray
XTerm*ScrollBar: false
XTerm*ScrollBar.DrawBorder: false
XTerm*loginShell: true



XTerm*faceName: Mono
XTerm*faceSize: 9
```

Could anyone say is it possible to make bold some text, wich color is e.g. color1 from my config? I've tried `XTerm*color1:  rgb:cd/00/00 bold`, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but it answers the
question I had when I googled and found your question.

You can make bold, underlined, reverse video, and blinking text, be
colored, *in addition* to being bold, underlined, reversed, or
blinking.  For example, you already have

```
XTerm*colorBD: white
XTerm*colorUL: SkyBlue
XTerm*colorBDMode: on
XTerm*colorULMode: on
```

which *replaces* bold and underlining with colors.  To get bold and
underlining and color *at the same time*, add

```
XTerm*veryBoldColors: 6
```

The documentation for the `veryBoldColors` resource in `man xterm` is

```
veryBoldColors (class VeryBoldColors)
  Specifies  whether  to  combine  video  attributes with colors
  specified by  colorBD,  colorBL,  colorRV  and  colorUL.   The
  resource value is the sum of values for each attribute:
    1 for reverse,
    2 for underline,
    4 for bold and
    8 for blink.

  The default is “0”.
```